# Dynamic Filter TextBox from ListBox Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have populated a column range cells into a UserForm ListBox (below is the code bulk). Now I want to create a TextBox in the same Form to dynamically filter the contents of that ListBox as I type my entry. How can I utilize the AutoFilter method (or other solution) to call the ListBox content? Thanks for your help.

```
Set rSource = Sheets("Property").Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown))

ListBox1.List = rSource.Cells.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

May by something like this help you:
When TextBox is changed it clearing Listbox1 and check which value from list contain that string if yes then macro add it to ListBox1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim cell As Range
Set rSource = Sheets("Property").Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown))

ListBox1.Clear
For Each cell In rSource
    If InStr(cell.Value, TextBox1.Text) <> 0 Then
        ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value

    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Set rSource = Sheets("Property").Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown))

ListBox1.List = rSource.Cells.Value
End Sub
```